# How add target="-blank" and open link in new browser?

Tags: php, html, css, r, shiny

I have below code. it pasts ID (in my Data) to a link. I would like to know where can I use  target="-blank" in this code to open it in a new browser?

```
DF <-data %>% 
mutate( link = paste0("<a href='https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=", ID, "&organism_id=1","'>Link</a>")) 

output:

<a href='https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=1912&organism_id=1'>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use **shiny** you can use `tags$a`:

```
tags$a(
  href = paste0("https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=", ID, "&organism_id=1"), 
  target = "_blank",
  "Link"
)
```

---

As per your comment:

```r
DF <- data %>% 
  mutate(
    link = as.character(tags$a(
      href = paste0("https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=", ID, "&organism_id=1"), 
      target = "_blank",
      "Link"
    ))
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! yes I use shiny. But i would like to add it as a new column in my table, then read that data for using in shiny. I have updated the question

Comment: @star See my update.

Answer (score 2):

```
link = paste0("<a ",'target="_blank"',' href="https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=', ID, '&organism_id=1">Link</a>')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mohammad. Thank for your solution. It also works well. But I don`t know how to accept both solutions (You and Stephane).

Comment: I didn't realize you could provide the target parameter before the href. It helped to see it laid out as such.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h4>Simple Link Open in New Tab</h4>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/hitechumair" target="_blank">Click Here</a>


<h4>Link with Button Open in New Tab</h4>
<button style="background-color:red;color:white;border-color:red;">
<a style="text-decoration:none;color:white;" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/hitechumair" target="_blank">Click Here</a></button>


<style>
button:hover{
background-color:black;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:overline;}

</style>
```

Comment: @Umair: Thank you !  but it doesn`t work in my case: I have tried " link = paste0("<a href='https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=", ID, "&organism_id=1",target="_blank" "'>Link</a>"))"    or  "link = paste0("<a href='https://enhancer.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/imagedb3.pl?form=presentation&show=1&experiment_id=" target="_blank" , ID, "&organism_id=1","'>Link</a>")) ". But it doesn`t work and I get error: unexpected token "="/ "_"